# How to get the bytes from opencv image matrix?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

If I have an opencv image that I read from a png file like this:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/to/path/test.png");
```

how do I get that image in bytes? I know using `img.data` returns an unsigned char* but that is not what I need. Any suggestions?

Comment: `img.data` is the image in bytes, so in what way is it not what you need?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you want, for example, a 250*250 image to return a 250*250 matrix so I would suggest using grey-scale instead of BGR

```py
imgData = cv2.imread(path, 0)
```

I believe this is written in C++ like this

```cpp
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(file_name);//It returns a matrix object
cv::Mat graymat;
cvtColor(img, graymat,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```